# How to call out daily value through period index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, period

I have a dataframe using periodindex (daily) starting from 1992-01-03.

I am trying to call out the data using period index, like `dataframe['1992-01-03']`, but it returned an error message--Key Error:'1992-01-03'. 
However, it works well if I call out by year or month, e.g., `dataframe['1992']`, or `dataframe['1992-01']`.

I can call out the daily value by using `dataframe.loc['1992-01-03']`.

Can anyone briefly explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `.loc`

```
dataframe['1992-01-03']
```

Is check the column

With `.loc` is search the index

```
dataframe.loc['1992-01-03']
```